# Div container with "arrow" type top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I need to make content blocks like this:

[image]

If it was only the shape itself, it wouldn't be a problem. But there are some issues:

- there will be images inside the white container that should end at that curve line (red lines), like overflow hidden, only it doesn't work on the curved edges.
- underneath it there will be a pattern/image of dark triangles you can see (so any option with rotated element on top of it with some color won't work)
- after the container there will be images too that goes underneath te container.

I think I could make layers easily with z-index games, but the main point are the images inside white container that shouldn't cross those arrow edges (overflow: hidden), plus making pattern and images (that go just after it) visible.

Here is my last shot that I have missed (with absolute positioned css triangles on top and the bottom) transfered in JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vhdtq7c1/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow-style">
  <span class="top-arr arrow"></span>
    <img src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/img-compression/len_std.jpg">
  <span class="bottom-arr arrow"></span>
</div>

<div class="content-between">
    <img src="http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/laplacians/lena_lap1.png">
</div>

<div class="arrow-style">
  <span class="top-arr arrow"></span>
  <span class="bottom-arr arrow"></span>
</div>

<div class="content-between">

</div>

<div class="arrow-style">
  <span class="top-arr arrow"></span>
  <span class="bottom-arr arrow"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background: url(https://images.blogthings.com/whatpatternisyourbrainquiz/pattern-2.jpg);
}
.arrow-style {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    height: 170px;
}
span.arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
.top-arr {
    border-width: 0 50vw 70px 50vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
    top: -69px;
}
.bottom-arr {
    border-width: 70px 50vw 0 50vw;
    border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
    bottom: -69px;
}

.content-between {
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
}
.arrow-style img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right:20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content-between img {
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
}
```

Maybe there are some javascript solutions for this ? I know it is better to use CSS only in similar cases, but if there is no other way

EDIT:
I don't want to do this with clip-paths as it has very poor browser support...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't get this to work. Borders can't contain images like this, so this simply won't work.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie are you sure of that :)

Comment: You're welcome to prove me wrong :)

Comment: You can do this with CSS and z-index.  You will need to create the images with some transparent areas.

Comment: @user2182349 could You explain more, what do You mean by that? Which images should have transparent areas?

Comment: You can try with multiple backgrounds - https://jsfiddle.net/uuk6q2ob/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I made it to work this way :

https://jsfiddle.net/b5ohf3n7/12/

I made two rotated containers and put white lines inside it. That way picture that is in the rotated container can end exactly by the line where arrow is made. Also background with all the background stuff below it is visible and looks good. Thanks for commenting and hope that helps for someone!

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="upper">
    <div class="content-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="left-container">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="lower-part"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="lower-part"></div>
        <img src="https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/robot_male_2.png" class="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="background">
    <div class="pattern-container">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
  z-index: 0;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://d5prcm06amy2t.cloudfront.net/mobile/mobile-hank04-shadow.png') left top no-repeat, url('http://www.quackit.com/pix/web_graphics/free_website_graphics/background_patterns/03b.jpg') left top repeat;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.upper {
  background-color: white;
  height: 208px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.lower-part {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.left {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
}

.content-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.left-container {
     padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: -60px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}

.right-container {
      padding: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: -60px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}

.pattern-container {
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```